# msp430 simple I/O Code

Tags: scanf, msp430

i'm working with msp430F5528 and using CCS to compile and run my codes, i couldnt understand why printf and scanf functions dont work, the code is working fine without errors but i cant see at my console what should be printed by printf function.

```c
#include <msp430F5528.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;  //STOP WDT

    P6DIR |= BIT0 + BIT1 + BIT2 + BIT3 + BIT4;  // SET P6 TO OUTPUT

    char i;

    printf("select a number \n");

    scanf("%c", &i);

    switch(i){
        case '1': P6OUT |= 0x00 ;
        break;

        case '2': P6OUT |= BIT0 ;
        break;

        case '3': P6OUT |= BIT1 ;
        break;

        case '4': P6OUT |= BIT1 + BIT0 ;
        break;

        case '5': P6OUT |= BIT2 ;
        break;

        case '6': P6OUT |= BIT2 + BIT0 ;
        break;

        case '7': P6OUT |= BIT2 + BIT1 ;
        break;

        case '8': P6OUT |= BIT2 + BIT1 + BIT0 ;
        break;

        case '9': P6OUT |= BIT3 ;
        break;

        case 'q': P6OUT |= BIT3 + BIT0 ;
        break;

        case 'w': P6OUT |= BIT3 + BIT1 ;
        break;

        case 'e': P6OUT |= BIT3 + BIT1 + BIT0 ;
        break;

        case 'r': P6OUT |= BIT3 + BIT2 ;
        break;

        case 't': P6OUT |= BIT3 + BIT2 + BIT0 ;
        break;

        case 'y': P6OUT |= BIT3 + BIT2 + BIT1 ;
        break;

        case 'u': P6OUT |= BIT3 + BIT2 + BIT1 + BIT0 ;
        break;

        default: printf("Fehler!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What console? How did you connect the MSP430F5528 to the keyboard and the screen?

Comment: i meant the console of CCS, and connected it to keyboard with a device called usb-debug interface

Comment: [Printf support for MSP430 CCSTUDIO compiler](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Printf_support_for_MSP430_CCSTUDIO_compiler); [Tips for using printf](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Tips_for_using_printf)

Comment: @user3754639  I think, I had a [similar problem](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59419/msp430-printf-through-spy-bi-wire-hangs).  (But I couldn't solve it, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 0):

You can open the console with the Window/Show View/Console menu. 
(Alt-Shift-Q, C)

Comment: i knew how to open the console of ccs, the problem is that nothing is printed to that console , should something be wrong with my settings or cant we use printf and scanf functions with msp430?